# R: Extending first column of matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I generated this matrix with `mat=matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), nrow = 2, ncol = 2)` and I got this result:

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6
```

How can I add the second and third column to the first, like this:

```
         [,1] 
    [1,]    1   
    [2,]    2    
    [3,]    3    
    [4,]    4
    [5,]    5 
    [6,]    6
```

Is there any specific function that can solve this even If I would have 10 columns and I want them all added to the first column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use just wrap with `matrix` and it returns a single column object

```
matrix(mat)
```